# Django static files not serving in Nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx

My first website with Django on hobby production.

I'am follow the setting guide this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04#checking-for-the-gunicorn-socket-file

my setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media/')
```

and my nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name MYIP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/azhimeblog/needhobby;
    }
   location /media/ {
        root /home/azhimeblog/needhobby;
    }


    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

This result

[image: result]

Comment: nginx should be serving static and media files in your setup. Can you have a look ngixn error logs to see what's wrong?  Have you ran `./manage.py collectstatic` command? Do you have `static` directory in `/home/azhimeblog/needhobby` full of static assets? Can nginx access that directory?

Comment: Ok my problem has been fix. but now i can't upload  images files and show error nginx: [emerg] location "/" is outside location